# linking 2 divs instead of only text

Tags: html, css

i have several images, with the image i have a link(text).

However i want both the text and image to click-able rather than just the text.

This is my code: html:

```
<div id="testimage">
  <div id="a1"><a href="http://mja.co.uk/">Awards</a></div>
</div>
```

(another image) :

```
  <div id="testimage1">
  <div id="a2"><a href="http://mja.co.uk/Events">Events</a></div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
  #testimage {

   background-image: url(images/mja1.jpg);height: 205px;width: 322px;   
 }
 #a1 a
 {position: absolute;font-size: 25px;color: #085da2;top: 503px;}
 #a1 a:hover
 {color:#085da2;opacity:0.5;}
```

as you can see the a1 has a link, however i need a link to testimage too.

i have tried :

HTML

```
 <a href="http://mja.co.uk/Events"><div id="testimage"></div></a>
```

CSS

```
 a{ display:block; }
```

with this; when I added the 2nd image, the whole page started to look different.

So am looking to have a link for both div.

Comment: I cant be asked to go make a fiddle. So can you please make a JSFiddle.

Comment: Is this what your looking for? [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/ucz5S/)

Comment: Yes, or at least show the complete HTML. And can you explain what the position:absolute is for, and why you're not just using img elements?

Comment: this is my complete html n css: http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/VS7Hb/

however, it shows it mismatch for some reason, ignore the output, what i need is to link both image and text

Comment: this is my site: http://mja.anytimeafter9.co.uk/

Comment: @al123 Look at my demo. Thats all you need.

Comment: yh looks good, however when i put my mouse on any white space and click then it opens the site. how do i only make it to the image.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you mean the whitespace next to the text then yes. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/ucz5S/1/)

Comment: yeh thats better, but if you look at this: http://mja.anytimeafter9.co.uk/ if you hover and the bottom 3 pictures, in the white space its showing the click, as i only want it for the image and text...

Comment: and when i do try clicking the last image, and automatically clicks another image :/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
<a href="http://mja.co.uk/Events">
    <img src="images/mja1.jpg"/>
    <span id="a2">Events</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`a { display: inline-block }` will "expand" the clickable area of the link to the full size of it's containing element, in this case, the `<div>`, yet holds the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the div in an a tag... `<a href=""><div id="whatever">The text</div></a>`